# Entity Framework LINQ Insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to use LINQ to insert an object in my database. My primary key is auto increment. Do I need to increment the id in my code or Entity Framework can do it?

I have my dbContext:

```
TravelAgencyEntities db = new TravelAgencyEntities();
```

I'm trying to insert a User object:

```
User newUser = new User();
        newUser.FirstName = firstName.Text.ToString();
        newUser.LastName = lastName.Text.ToString();
        newUser.Email = email.Text.ToString();
        newUser.Password = password.Text.ToString();

        db.Users.Add(newUser);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

It returns an exception:

```
{"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}
```

I think that error is because I do not set the id in my object, but it should be auto increment. Does anyone know the problem?

The INNER ERROR:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'User' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
```

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: So...what's the `InnerException`?

Comment: +  InnerException {"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'User' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."} System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

Comment: Having identity_insert set to off will not allow for a specific value to be inserted into the column in the table marked as an identity field.  If you wish to insert a specific value into a column that is marked as an identity, you need to set the identity_insert to on with the statement SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[User] ON

Comment: Does your Id property have the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute applied to it?  That will let EF know not to send a value for it for inserts since the DB handles it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use code first, probably have set following code in DbContext OnModelCreating.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .Property(a => a.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
}
```

Or set as attribute like  following

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    .....
}
```

you must change None to Identity. Identity option is default for key.